# Inheritance in C# COM

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have following code for the class Item. When I use this code in VBA, I can easily create a new instance and access the properties. But the moment I try to inherit from `ListViewItem`, its builds alright in C#, but the COM object breaks in VBA when creating a new instance.

```
//Working 
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class Item 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }   
}

//Fails 
public class Item :ListViewItem
```

VBA

```
  1: Dim x As CSActiveX.Item
  2: Set x = New CSActiveX.Item
```

With Inheritance this part (Line 2) throws the error: `Automation Error`.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: I have marked `Item` as `ComVisible` and `ListViewItem` class is readonly as it inherits from `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem` instead of having a flat POCO?

Comment: what is a flat POCO? Anyways, I am inherting from `ListViewItem` because I want to return an actual item from a listview control in C#. It is a custom .net control and via COM its being used in VBA

Comment: Can you update your code with what you really have?  For instance, you say you have `ComVisible` set on class `Item`, but we don't see that.  Anything else missing as well?

Comment: bit confused.... on the second line of the code can't you see `[ComVisible(true)]`

Comment: Yes, but that's the non-inherited version of your code.  In the inherited sample code, the `Item` class doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: ah, that's just a line. I didn't repeat the code here in question. But actually,  if I just add inheritance to the code as depicted at the upper part. So `[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class Item :ListViewItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }   
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `regasm` then make sure you use `Codebase` switch.